# Ubuntu Core on Raspberry Pi 4 Install Configuration Too Fast

Tags: system-installation, configuration, raspberrypi, ubuntu-core

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Core 22 (and I tried 20 as well) on a Raspberry Pi 4, but am being faced with a super fast reset on the install configuration console. I have about 5 seconds after the first time I hit the enter key until it returns me back to the original prompt to "Press enter to configure". It's way faster than shown in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aekZhezFCHM).

I'm using image ubuntu-core-22-armhf+raspi.img.xz, but experienced the same issue with ubuntu-core-20-armhf+raspi.img.xz

I looked in the [Configuration Options Documentation](https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/ubuntu-core-configuration), but didn't see anything there that looks like it would help.

Is there some way to increase the time I have to make the configuration changes, or some changes to the snaps that I can make so I don't have to even go through the configuration prompts?

Comment: I think you're supposed to wait until it does all the first-boot voodoo that happens on core. It's a bit bad that it says "Press enter to confgure" while it's doing all that first-run stuff. I believe you just need to wait longer.

Comment: I reformatted the SD card and copied the image over to it and tried it again. I've waited more than 20 minutes and still get the fast recycle back to the "Press enter to configure" prompt. There isn't any time to try to configure the network.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? Experiencing the same problem and it’s completely blocked me.

Comment: No I didn't get it to work